# Mockito verify asynchronous methods

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

I have an method that need to write test (I use instrumented `androidTest`, but this also happen with JVM unit test):

```
void fooNeedToBeTested(String paramString) {
    if(paramString.isEmpty())
        return

    // queue Runnable in worker thread to do something
    BackgroundWorker.queueTask(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            repository.doSomething(paramString);
        }
    });
}
```

I need to verify `doSomething()` is called so I write a unit test:

```
@Test
void testVerifyAsyncCallback() {
    presenter.fooNeedToBeTested("string args");

    Mockito.verify(repository).doSomething("string args");
}
```

But the problem is: the test finish executed before the async code inside `run()` method has been reached. Then Mockito cannot verify it has been run or not.

So how can we tell test runner to wait for the async code to be executed, then inform Mockito to verify?

Comment: Try using [`verify with timeout`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/verification/VerificationWithTimeout.html).

Comment: @second but what if I only need to verify it is run or not, and don't care about the delay time?

Comment: Using the timeout should verify that the method has been executed within the given time frame (which is basically the `wait` your asking for). -- If you want to use another approach you could define a `lock` within the `doSomething` (by using `thenAnswer`) and actively block the test unitl this point has been reached,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we have 2 solutions:

- First is verify with [timeout()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/verification/VerificationWithTimeout.html)
- Second is create a "fake" `BackgroundWorker` (in src/test folder) to call `Runnable#run()` directly, without queuing into background thread.